# Closed Connection: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection jboss 7

Tags: java, performance, jboss7.x, ibatis

We are facing below exception while fetching the CLOB from the database.

```
Closed Connection: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.sql.CLOB.getDBAccess(CLOB.java:1510) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
        at oracle.sql.CLOB.getCharacterStream(CLOB.java:361) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
```

We are getting this exception only fetching the CLOB from the database and this is really very random.

We are using jboss7.0.2 with ojdbc6.jar for oracle 11.2.0.3 and ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.9.final.jar

standalone.xml configuration is as follows

```
<driver>
  ojdbc6
</driver>
<pool>
  <max-pool-size>
    25
  </max-pool-size>
  <prefill>
    false
  </prefill>
  <use-strict-min>
    false
  </use-strict-min>
  <flush-strategy>
    FailingConnectionOnly
  </flush-strategy>
 </pool>
 <security>
   <security-domain>
     TestDSRealm
   </security-domain>
 </security>
 <validation>
   <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
   <validate-on-match>
     false
   </validate-on-match>
   <background-validation>
     false
   </background-validation>
   <use-fast-fail>
     false
   </use-fast-fail>
   <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
   <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
   </validation>
   <statement>
    <prepared-statement-cache-size>
                                100
    </prepared-statement-cache-size>
   </statement>
```

Are we doing anything wrong here? Any idea?

Thanks for your help..

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I changed the mapping from Clob to String ( [Loading Clob data as a String (eager) via Hibernate's org.hibernate.Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581549/loading-clob-data-as-a-string-eager-via-hibernates-org-hibernate-query) ) and after all worked.