# Loading Clob data as a String (eager) via Hibernate's org.hibernate.Query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, apache-flex

I need to fetch a String from a clob Oracle column using Hibernate *without* lazy loading and without using a Criteria query. It currently returns a proxy class (ex. $Proxy30) but I need a String (or something I can convert to a String).  The proxy is for oracle.sql.CLOB according to the debugger.

When I use a Criteria query (with just the regular Column annotation mapping for this field), this works just fine. But we have one area where we "build" a custom SQL query which uses a simple org.hibernate.Query and AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE, and this is where the proxy problem arises. Since it's just an org.hibernate.Query, I assume it's not referring to my annotation mappings at all, so I don't think messing with annotations will help.

Since using a Criteria query is not an option here (we're building a query string for some advanced search reporting requirements), what should I be researching to find a workaround?  Or even better, what's my path of least effort to do this?

Also this is for an Apache Flex application - I need the type to be a String (rather than CLOB) to be used in a data transfer object to the client.. perhaps other Flex devs have solved this problem before?

```
Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSqlQuery(sql);
query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
List... resultlist = ...query.list();
resultlist.iterator();
//iterate results...
Object shouldBeAString = (Object)result.get("CLOB_COLUMN_NAME");
//The object above should be a String but is a $Proxy30
//Debugger shows an "h" property of type SerializableClobProxy
```

If I need a custom "ResultTransformer" - any links to decent docs for doing that would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem, various links suggested upgrading spring to 4.0.1+ and hibernate to 4.3.x but this didn't make any difference. Then I came across this link which resolved my issue. The author writes a custom ResultTransformer for the Clob and then setting this as the as the transformer for you query instead of AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.

http://javatechtricks.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/hibernate-clob-to-string-conversion.html

Code from the article below:

```
public class MyResultTransformer extends BasicTransformerAdapter {

 public final static MyResultTransformer INSTANCE;
 static {
  INSTANCE = new MyResultTransformer();
 }

 private MyResultTransformer() {

 }
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Override
 public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
  Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++) {
   Object t = tuple[i];
   if (t != null && t instanceof Clob) {
    Clob c = (Clob) tuple[i];
    try {
     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     IOUtils.copy(c.getAsciiStream(), bos);
     t = new String(bos.toByteArray());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
   map.put(aliases[i], t);
  }
  return map;
 }
}
```

Then in your code replace

```
query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
```

with

```
query.setResultTransformer(MyResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
```

In addition, an alternative solution could be to change the column type, I havn't tried it myself.

> **JDBC large objects** 
>   The types blob and clob provide mappings for the
>   Blob and Clob classes in the java.sql package. If you are dealing with
>   truly large values, your best bet is to declare the properties as
>   either Blob or Clob—even though this introduces an explicit JDBC
>   dependency to your data object, it easily allows Hibernate to leverage
>   JDBC features **to lazily load the property value only if you need it**.
>
> If you are not worried that the data is too huge, you can spare
>   yourself this direct JDBC interface, declare the property type as
>   String or byte[ ], and map it using text or binary. These correspond
>   to SQL column types of CLOB and VARBINARY (RAW in Oracle, BYTEA in
>   PostgreSQL), respectively, and **the values are loaded immediately into
>   the properties when the object is loaded**.

Source: http://oreilly.com/java/excerpts/harnessing-hibernate/hibernate-types.html

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this, I modified a little bit the solution to use the clob method `getSubString` : there is one less exception to catch.

```
public Object transformTuple(final Object[] tuple, final String[] aliases) {
        final Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>(tuple.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < tuple.length; i++) {
            Object object = tuple[i];
            if (object instanceof Clob) {
                object = clobToString((Clob) object);
            }
            final String alias = aliases[i];
            if (alias != null) {
                result.put(alias, object);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String clobToString(final Clob clob) {
        try {
            return clob.getSubString(1, (int) clob.length());
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while converting clob : " + clob, e);
        }
    }
```